# Why can I remove an edge from a cycle that is part of a connected graph

Tags: graph-theory

I've been trying to figure this out for awhile now. But if I have a connected graph, which contains a cycle, why can I remove an edge from the cycle and still have a connected graph?

Comment: Think of what the graph should look like if upon removing an edge it becomes disconnected.

Comment: Imagine the graph is a triangle. Removing an edge still leaves a connected graph with no cycles.

Comment: Let the removed edge be the edge from vertex $v$ to vertex $w$. Can you see another way to get from $v$ to $w$?

Answer (score 1):

Partition the vertices that form a cycle into two disjoint sets, $L$ and $R$ such that all nodes in $L,R$ respectively form sub-paths that are part of the cycle. Let the other nodes that are not part of the cycle be in $N$.

[image: Graphic]

There should be exactly two edges that connect the nodes from $L$ to $R$ since the set of node in $L \cup R$ form a cycle. Removing one edge still leaves $L$ connected to $R$ which means the graph is still connected because the remaining nodes in $N$ are connected to either $L$ or $R$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be a connected graph and suppose $C$ is a cycle of $G$.

Consider the subgraph $G-e$, where $e=uv$ is an edge of $C$.

Removing $e$ converts $C$ into a path from $u$ to $v$ having the same vertices as $C$,  hence the vertices of $C$ are all in the same component, $A$ say, of $G-e$.

But if we then add edge $e$ back, it will be an edge connecting the two vertices $u,v$ of $A$, so adding $e$ won't change the number of components.

Thus in the transition from $G-e$ back to $G$, the number of components remains the same, hence since $G$ is connected, so is $G-e$.